# Why does this trick not work for me?

Tags: windows, batch-file

[What's the coolest hack you've seen or done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192479/whats-the-coolest-hack-youve-seen-or-done/192691#192691)

I just changed `mplayer` to `woplayer`,
and I don't see what this does:

```
findstr /I /R %1 dirlist.txt > playlist.txt
```

What's `dirlist.txt`?

Answer (score 2):

That meant to be you full playlist, i.e. all your music files. You can make one by typing:

```
dir c:\*.mp3 /s /b > dirlist.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Dirlist.txt is a text file with the list of the songs. With findstr you are searching inside this file for a pattern matched with %1, the first argument passed when calling to this .bat file.

So, if you don't have a file with the list of your songs, this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

dirList.txt appears to be a text file you have already filled in containing the filenames of all your music tracks (one on each line of the file).

The batch file then filters out only the filenames that include the string that you specified (using a regex match), and makes a new, shorter list (playlist.txt) which can then be sent to your music player application to get it to play those tracks only.

Note that "woplayer" has to support playing a playlist in the same way as "mplayer", or the trick won't work - you may not necessarily be able to just substiture one program for another.